# Android Mediaplayer(Music Player)

Tags: media-player, android-mediaplayer, audio-player

I am using musicplayer as a part of my app. I have given (button)onclicklistener from homepage(activity) to musicplayer(activity). And a button in musicplayer to Homepage. When i click on the musicplayer button in homepage the song starts playing and everything works fine. When i go to homepage through intent and click on the musicplayer button in homepage the old song which started before is playing and a new media player is created and a new song is playing along with that. Musicplayer UI is updated to the new song . Multiple clicks in musicplayer button creates multiple songs playing together . I just want to resume only the music started playing in  first intent to music player and not want to replace mediaplayer with new one.I have referred several sites but cant fix this. can any one help me with this.
The musicplayer i have used is a from a link 
http://www.androidhive.info/2012/03/android-building-audio-player-tutorial/

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stack Overflow is for questions about programs and programming, not general advice about programs. To get help here please show the code for smallest complete and self contained program that demonstrates your question. As it stands your question is likely to deleted, so see the help pages for how to write a good question.

Comment: https://github.com/protocol10/SangeetPlayer u can refer this